# ABout simple Html Dom method ->load_file

Tags: php, html, dom

i wrote this code, and it work

```
<?php
include ('require/simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');

echo $html=file_get_html('http://www.site.com');
?>
```

Now  i want it to work using object method
i did this:

```
<?php
include ('require/simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
echo $html->load_file('http://www.site.com');
?>
```

i got blank screen.

any help will be  grateful

Thanks.

---

with this error reporting actived

```
 <?php
 ini_set('display_errors',1);
 ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
 error_reporting(-1);

include ('require/simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
echo $html->load_file('http://www.site.com');
?>
```

I still get blank page

Comment: Turn on error reporting and tell us what you get

Answer (score 0):

If you check manual 
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

to dump dom using oop method you should use

```
// Dumps the internal DOM tree back into string 
$str = $html->save();

// Dumps the internal DOM tree back into a file 
$html->save('result.htm');
```